# How to get a desired order in Bibliography with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

The problem in a nutshell is this:  I frequently have to cite items (books, articles, etc.) in different translations.  For example, I often need to cite an article in its English translation and in its original language, for example, German, Latin, etc.  I also frequently need to cite different items by the same author from the same year.  So, for example, suppose that A-Ger is a German original and A-Eng is its English translation.  Similarly, suppose that B-Ger is a German original and B-Eng is its English translation.  The author of the articles is the same and the year of publication is the same.  I would like these items to be listed in the actual bibliography at the end of the document in the order A-Ger, A-Eng, B-Ger, B-Eng.  But, because the author and year are the same for all, BibTeX ends up putting the items in alphabetical order, I believe by the article's title!  So, the order in the bibliography comes out sometimes like B-Ger, A-Eng, B-Eng, A-Ger or some other unnatural order.  This is unhelpful.  I need the German version of the first article first, then the English translation of that article, then the German version of the second article, followed by the English translation of the second article.

Can anybody suggest how I can accomplish this?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution because I suppose that you cite the articles in the same order you want to have.

You can change the style of your bibliography into 'unsrt', so the order in the bibliography will be the same as the order of the '\cite' (for french speakers, I've found the answer here http://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/hH2nIgjW/ordre-des-references-dans-la-bibliographie)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Blabla \cite{A-Ger} (the translation \cite{A-Eng}).

blablabla \cite{B-Ger} (the translation \cite{B-Eng})
blabla

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{file_biblio}  

\end{document}
```